# It is ok to to edit posts to add tags that are related to answers rather than questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

I'd like to know if it is ok to add a tag to a post that help categorizing it but it is more related to the answer rather than to the question.

This doubt is related to this question [How to create an Ubuntu LiveUSB that will also boot on a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/589595/creating-bootable-usb-to-install-ubuntu) where I have answered by suggesting to use unetbootin.

It is ok if I retag the question with the [unetbootin](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unetbootin), or should tags only describe questions and not anwers?